# fetch media from internet and storing in imageview

Tags: android

I have implemented application in which i am using tabs and want to fetch the images,audio,video from server and show on appropiate tab.

can anybody help me ..

Thanks Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html